# Random Engine - follow up

Tags: c++, random, c++14

I have ported the code from my previous question "*[Generate a random numbers class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71313/generate-a-random-numbers-class)*" to C++14 and made a few modifications.

How can I improve it further?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

template<typename T>
class Random
{
    template <typename U>
    static auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<U>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution<U>>{};

    template <typename U>
    static auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<U>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution<U>>{};


public:
    Random()
        : mRandomEngine(std::random_device()())
    {}

    auto operator()(T max)
    {
        decltype(dist<T>()) uniformDistribution(0, max - 1);
        return uniformDistribution(mRandomEngine);
    }

    auto operator()(T min, T max)
    {
        decltype(dist<T>()) uniformDistribution(min, max);
        return uniformDistribution(mRandomEngine);
    }

private:
    std::mt19937            mRandomEngine;
};

int main()
{
    Random<int> random;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        std::cout << random(1, 8) << '\n';

    Random<float> randomf;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        std::cout << randomf(1.f, 8.f) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Asserting our preconditions**

Your class requires `T` to either be an integral type or a floating point type. If it's not, you'll get a compile error at point of use on `operator()` instead of at point of declaration. Let's fix that:

```
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "!");
```

**Unnecessary Complexity**

We are conditionally selecting a distribution type based on whether or not `T` is integral or floating point. Once we assert that it's one or the other, we can simply use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
using dist_type = std::conditional_t<
                      std::is_integral<T>::value,
                      std::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
                      std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>;
```

And just use that:

```
T operator()(T min, T max)
{
    dist_type uniformDistribution(min, max);
    return uniformDistribution(mRandomEngine);
}
```

This is a lot more direct. No extra template arguments. Also `auto` on return type is best reserved for those cases where you need it. This is a random engine generating `T`s, so it really had better return a `T`.

**Single-value?**

Consider the difference between our distributions. [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is closed:

> Produces random integer values i, uniformly distributed on the closed interval [a, b]

but [`uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) is open:

> Produces random floating-point values i, uniformly distributed on the interval [a, b)

This suggests one of two potential implementations

1. Pass this difference onto your users. They should be aware that for floating point `T`s, it will be open on the top end.
2. Make your implementation always open on top end of the distribution.

Right now, we're half and half. It's fairly unexpected that:

```
Random<int> r;
r(1, 6); // can return 6
r(0, 6); // can return 6
r(6);    // cannot return 6
```

I'd recommend option (1):

```
T operator()(T max) {
    return (*this)(0, max);
}
```

**Prefer Braces**

Where you have:

```
: mRandomEngine(std::random_device()())
```

Prefer to brace-initialize the `random_device`:

```
: mRandomEngine(std::random_device{}())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you leave out the default-constructor, your class will become an aggregate, and all members will be default-constructed, leading to the same result.

Though one could also explicitly initialize the random-generator differently at need.